# Sync single photos from Mac to iPhone

Tags: iphone, mac, data-synchronization, photos.app, photos

I'm trying so send photos from my Mac onto my iPhone. I don't want to sync whole folders.

Is it possible to "sync" single selected photos without deleting all the others? Granted, "sync" is the probably the wrong word here.

I know I can send them via email to my iPhone, but assuming that I have no internet, what else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its difficult to give the best answer without knowing which photo manager you use and how often you'd to transfer a photo. For rare transfers, email and Dropbox are good solutions.

For a more sophisticated approach, I use a smart album in Aperture together with a keyword called "Sync." Now whenever I add the Sync keyword to a photo on my Mac, it is automatically added to the Sync album, which is set (in iTunes) to sync with my iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Photo syncing on the iPhone is kind of lame.  Apple wants you to commit 100% to iPhoto or Aperture and if you don't then you don't get much support.

Probably easiest is to create a separate folder just for photos you want to put on your iPhone and then sync photos from that folder.  You can put aliases in the folder so you don't have to move/copy the photos from wherever it is you want to keep them.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this best just like Ash had suggested, although another route If you are using iPhoto or Aperture is to make Albums & add any photo from any event/project into the album(s) you want manually. You can also try creating one album called "iPhone Pictures", and then either drag and drop the pictures you want to put onto the iPhone into that album, or use the +to button in the toolbar. Then sync that selected album through the photos tab in iTunes while the iPhone is plugged in. :-)